# XML transformation with save path

Tags: xml

I have the follow file XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child1>
        <node>
                .... node attributes 
        </node>            
        <node>
                .... node attributes 
        </node>            
        <subchild1>
            <node>
                    .... node attributes 
            </node>            
            <subchild1>
            </child1>
            <child2>
                <node>
                .... node attributes 
                </node>            
                ....
            </child2>
.....
</parent>
```

Arbitrary number of nodes, only one element node has attributes, all other elements are needed to preserve the hierarchy.

I need transform xml into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>         
   <node>
     <path>parent\child1</path>
     .... node attributes 
   </node>            
   <node>
     <path>parent\child2</path>
     .... node attributes 
   </node>            
   <node>
     <path>parent\child1\subchild1</path>
     .... node attributes 
   </node>            
   .....
 </parent>
```

That is to deploy elements of type node in the list and add to it an attribute [path] to each element. Attribute shows the path for node in the hierarchy.

The technology is expected to be used XSLT version 2.0.

Comment: What type of tech do you have available to you to make these transformations? XSLT would be very well suited to making this transformation, but even then different XSLT engines will support different XSLT versions. Please edit your question to provide more details about you intend to implement the this transformation.